# Heisenberg equation of motion and continuum limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, spin-models, spin-chains

Given the quite simple Hamiltonian
$$\hat{\mathcal{H}}=\sum_n\big(\hat{S}_n^+\hat{S}^-_{n+1}+\hat{S}_n^-\hat{S}^+_{n+1}\big)$$
on a 1D spin chain, it basically interchanges two spins lying next to each other. Macroscopically this results in the spin density to possess a transport equation like normal diffusion:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle \hat{S}_n^z\rangle=D\frac{\partial^2}{\partial n^2}\langle \hat{S}_n^z\rangle.$$
To proof this I thought about using the Heisenberg equation of motion and "apply" the continuum limit, so my hope was that by calculating
$$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{S}_n^z=i[\hat{\mathcal{H}},\hat{S}_n^z]=i\big(\hat{S}_n^-\hat{S}^+_{n+1}-\hat{S}_n^+\hat{S}^-_{n+1}-\hat{S}_{n-1}^-\hat{S}^+_{n}+\hat{S}_{n-1}^+\hat{S}^-_{n}\big)$$
I somehow could relate this back to
$$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{S}_n^z=D'\cdot\Delta_a^2\hat{S}_n^z,$$
with the second order finite difference $\Delta_a^2$, and then let the chain size $a\to0$ to arrive at the desired equation. There are several issues I have: 1) How do I get from the $S^+$'s and $S^-$'s back to the $S^z$ operator? 2) How can I get the diffusion constant from this approach? 3) Can this approach even work or is wrong in the first place?

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

**Edit:** In this case I shouldn't use the Heisenberg picture but the Ehrenfest theorem, so my equation becomes
$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\hat{S}_n^z\rangle=i\big(\langle\hat{S}_n^-\hat{S}^+_{n+1}\rangle-\langle\hat{S}_n^+\hat{S}^-_{n+1}\rangle-\langle\hat{S}_{n-1}^-\hat{S}^+_{n}\rangle+\langle\hat{S}_{n-1}^+\hat{S}^-_{n}\rangle\big).$$

Comment: WHat exactly is the averaging in the equation that you are trying to prove? The relation might hold for the averages, but not for the operators. Also, how do you eprform expansion in $n$, i.e. the passage to teh continuum limit? You will have products like $S_n^+S_n^-$, which could give you $S_z$.

Comment: @Vadim It is averaged over all possible states of spin chains of infinite length. $S_n^+S_n^-$ would give me a linear combination of $S^2$ and $S_n^z$ operators, but I have $S_n^+S_{n+1}^-$.

Comment: You have $S_nS_{n+1}$ in the discrete limit - you need to pass to continuum,a nd it looks tricky in this problem.